# Starting a program in a chroot environment returns immediately

Tags: linux, bash, chroot

I am working in a virtual environment, trying to start open vm tools in a chroot environment.
I tested with bash and it seems to work fine.
I used `./configure --options --prefix=/home/chroot_env` to install the program, then using ldd on vmtoolsd, i copied the corresponding libraries to the `/lib` directory.

Now when I start `chroot /home/chroot_env /bin/vmtoolsd`, nothing happens, the chroot returns directly. Launching the same binary in the normal environment does work.

Does someone have an idea why it isn't working, the correct libraries are there, and it works with bash.

EDIT : strace showed that vmtoolsd is trying to access `/dev/console`, I added `mount --bind /dev/ /home/chroot_env/dev/` but it is still failing.

EDIT2 : another strace showed it was looking for another plugin loaded dynamically, i added it and it worked, conclusion `strace` is great for debugging such issue!

Comment: Does your `/home/chroot_env` have sufficient rootfs? I mean, does it have the necessary tools, like `/home/chroot_env/bin/bash`, `/home/chroot_env/bin/vmtoolsd` etc? Does it also have necessary shared libraries etc?

Comment: I added bash and vmtoolsd to the correct directories indeed, and copied the libraries needed, there might be a missing binary but I don't know a way of finding about it.

Comment: See if you can get [`ldd`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=ldd) working inside chroot...

Comment: Have you tried to use strace to see what happens?

Comment: @Maxime strace showed that vmtoolsd is trying to access to /dev/console, i edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @Maxime using strace helped me find the solution, should you post a solution that tells to use strace or should I post the solution of mounting /dev/console, I feel like the way I found the error is more important than the error in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a program and nothing happens, you can always run it with `strace` in order to see which syscalls are made. This is an easy way to obtain the list of the files (regular or not) that are opened. In your case, check that your program doesn't try to access a file that is not in the chroot.